# Where in angular/ngrx application to put logic for saving state to local storage

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, local-storage, ngrx

I have an angular application which uses @ngrx for state management. Within this application I have a piece of logic which subscribes to certain views of the state and saves them to local storage when they change. The code works as expected but I currently have it placed in my app component which seems like the wrong place for it. Can somebody suggest what the best place to put this logic would be?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

import * as fromRoot from './state-management/reducers';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(
        private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
    ){
        // Persist the user, with things to local storage
        Observable.combineLatest(
            store.select(fromRoot.getAuthUser),
            store.select(fromRoot.getThings),
            (user, things) => {
                return {...user, things: things};
            }
        ).subscribe(user => {
            let oldUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({...oldUser, user: user}));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about adding https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage We have used it successfully to persist data on app refresh :)

Comment: @Alex I had a brief look at it but it seems a bit overkill to introduce a new library to replace ~12 lines of code.

Comment: Ah, sure thing. If you only need it for a few lines, that is understandable :)

Comment: You could use the angular `APP_INITIALIZER` token to move that code out of the component.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you simply to use an existing package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-store-localstorage

His author definitely already found a suitable place.
If you want still to use your own implementation, then I would suggest to check his source code to understand triggers he uses for updates: https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage/blob/master/src/index.ts#L289